# Recursive Regex with a Pattern Matching only on Start of Match before Recursion?

Tags: python, regex, pypi-regex

I'm trying to find matching parentheses where there are also some more in the middle. I have the following regex that does that, it matches the parenthesis to find the one associated with it. What I need now is that it also searches a prefix for example "Test". It however recurses the entire pattern. I can't simply include "Test" in the start of the pattern. I also only want it to match when the prefix starts with "Test" and not just match any parentheses.

I want to replace the "Test( ... )" with something else, so it'd be preferable if it was one pattern so I can just use `regex.sub()`.

```
import regex

# want to match 'Test(' prefix specifically
regex.search('\(([^()]|(?R))*\)', '... () ... Test(123, Test(123, (3), 3))')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the case when you need to use [*subroutines*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html). Here, you need to enclose the recursed pattern in a capturing group and then use `(?1)` construct to recurse it:

```
import regex
m = regex.search(r'Test(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))', 'Test(123, Test(123, (3), 3))')
if m:
    print(m.group()) # => Test(123, Test(123, (3), 3))
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/IEOD41030).

**Details**

- `Test` - a prefix word
- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))`  - Capturing group 1 (that will be recursed with `(?1)`):

  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - zero or more reptitions of

    - `[^()]++` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` (possessive match for better efficiency)
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - a subroutine to recurse Capturing group #1 subpattern
  - `\)`  - a `)` char.